# Mysql: Clients with missing monthly data

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.5

I have table with following fields

```
id
client_id
monthly_date
page_counts
```

I am trying to get list of clients with date missing for page_counts

```
   SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT monthly_date as months from stats_entry group by monthly_date  ) AS m
    LEFT JOIN  stats_entry  ep
   ON m.months = ep.monthly_date 
   group by client_id, monthly_date
```

But it still shows clients with available dates only with left join?
What i am missing?

Comment: LEFT JOIN doesnt generate dates that dont exists in table.. you need to use a calender table

Comment: In  your stats_entry  table you have entry for all the months ?? s

Comment: only months from current year.

Comment: Raymond Nijland SELECT monthly_date as months from stats_entry group by monthly_date ( it gets all dates)